# Getting "wrong number of arguments" while adding values to an empty array

Tags: jmeter

I have two following arrays (note: given array is a sample part of the original array as it have more than 2K values).

```
parsedResultBD = [accounts:[
 [name: "Perf", uuid: "17e9b276-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
 [name: "MIB01", uuid: "1cd21e7c-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
 [name: "MIB02", uuid: "203be7e6-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
 [name: "Inflammation", uuid: "234d02b2-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
 [name: "MIB03", uuid: "26e7f56c-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
 [name: "Test_Study", uuid: "2a2517be-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"]], 
  status: 'OK', 
  page: [rows: 5000, more: 0, number: 1]]
```

and

```
filteredStudyName = ["Inflammation","Perf","Test_Study"]
```

Want to add the UUID from `parsedResultBD`  to an empty array which have the name same in `filteredStudyName`. The code is printing the UUID but while adding I am getting,

```
2023-06-11 11:06:12,362 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyName_Processer: UUID : 17e9b276-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002
2023-06-11 11:06:12,363 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyName_Processer: UUID : 234d02b2-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002
2023-06-11 11:06:12,363 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyName_Processer: UUID : 2a2517be-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002
2023-06-11 11:06:12,363 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, StudyName_Processer
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:231) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:968) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:585) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

Code Block:

```
def bdConverter = new JsonSlurper();
def responseBDTemp = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def responseBD = bdConverter.parseText(responseBDTemp);
def resultStudyUUIDCollector = [];
def parsedResultBD = responseBD.accounts;
def filteredStudyName = ["Inflammation","Perf","Test_Study"]
parsedResultBD.each {
  entryVal ->
    for (tempValueOfStudy in filteredStudyName) {
      if (tempValueOfStudy == entryVal.name) {
        log.info('UUID : ' + entryVal.uuid);
        resultStudyUUIDCollector.add(entryVal.uuid as String);
        resultStudyUUIDCollector << entryVal.uuid; //tried with this also getting similar error
      }
    }
}

log.info(resultStudyUUIDCollector)
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def emptyArray = []

filteredStudyName.each { name ->
    emptyArray.add(parsedResultBD.accounts.find { account -> account.name == name }.uuid)
}
```

Full code snippet from your question data just in case:

```
def parsedResultBD = [accounts: [
        [name: "Perf", uuid: "17e9b276-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
        [name: "MIB01", uuid: "1cd21e7c-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
        [name: "MIB02", uuid: "203be7e6-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
        [name: "Inflammation", uuid: "234d02b2-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
        [name: "MIB03", uuid: "26e7f56c-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"],
        [name: "Test_Study", uuid: "2a2517be-081a-11ee-be56-0242ac120002"]],
                      status  : 'OK',
                      page    : [rows: 5000, more: 0, number: 1]]

def filteredStudyName = ["Inflammation", "Perf", "Test_Study"]

def emptyArray = []

filteredStudyName.each { name ->
    emptyArray.add(parsedResultBD.accounts.find { account -> account.name == name }.uuid)
}

log.info('Generated array: ' + emptyArray)
```

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri, as always worked without fail.

Comment: How to pass this array to a for each controller and run it through ?

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, checkout the below change will fix your ask,

```
def bdConverter = new JsonSlurper();
def responseBDTemp = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def responseBD = bdConverter.parseText(responseBDTemp);
def resultStudyUUIDCollector = [];
def parsedResultBD = responseBD.accounts;
def filteredStudyName = ["Inflammation","Perf","Test_Study"]
parsedResultBD.each {
  entryVal ->
    for (tempValueOfStudy in filteredStudyName) {
      if (tempValueOfStudy == entryVal.name) {
        log.info('UUID : ' + entryVal.uuid);
        resultStudyUUIDCollector.add(entryVal.uuid as String);
      }
    }
}

log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(resultStudyUUIDCollector).toPrettyString());
```